# NSTimeInterval format for POST with JSON objective-c to DateTime .net format

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I retrieve the NSTimeInterval as follows:

```
NSTimeInterval milisecondedDate = ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000);
```

Which logs this:
***UNIX Timestamp: "1307710190993.865967"***

I only want the value before the dot to send with JSON like this:

***"/Date(1307710131826+0200)/"***

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Get the current timestamp in milliseconds since 1970 UNIX Timestamp.

```
NSTimeInterval millisecondedDate = ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000);
```

Format the milliesecondedDate to a string with no decimals.

```
NSString* formattedMilliseconds = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", millisecondedDate];
```

Set up the timestamp in DateTime .net format.

```
NSString *startOfDateFormat = @"/Date(";
NSString *endOfDateFormat = @"+0200)/";
NSString *dateTimeNow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",startOfDateFormat, formattedMilliseconds, endOfDateFormat];
```

There is probably a much better solution for doing this, but this worked for me for now.

Comment: endOfDateFormat depends on daylight saving time. This should be calculated rather than hard coded.

Comment: Yes, I should have pointed that out. But the questions is about the formatting structure of the timestamp. It was just hardcoded for the clarity of the example. Thanks